# updating existing customer fields from pre chat live agent

Tags: salesforce

suppose an existing contact starts chat via salesforce live agent and fills the pre-chat form. How do I update contact fields via post chat form as no action is taken for an existing contact except for creating a new case.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger on the case that will use the data on the case and update the contact if necessary.